# sudo inside Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sudo

We have the following setup:

1. We have few UNIX boxes.
2. There are users provisioned to these boxes (ex: *spande*).
3. These users have limited privileges, but can do sudo to elevate the permissions (sudo user: *admin*).
4. The sudo happens without any password.

We have a CICD tool in Jenkins which uses these Unix boxes as slave. We have *spande* credentials to login into this unix servers via Jenkins.

We are using Jenkins Pipeline Scripts (groovy). All is well, but we want the Jenkins script to run with a higher previlige and hence need to know:

1. how can we do sudo within Jenkins script? (*sudo su - admin*)
2. is this a best practice / good approach to sudo within a script? If not, what other alternative we have? (our Unix server team is not ready to create a password enabled user with higher privileges due to organisation policies)

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: set Jenkins service to run under the user who has higher privileges. 
Or you can allow some commands for the current user to execute without sudo. You can try `NOPASSWD`  rule to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking using `sudo` as part of a script is fine, so long as you're not granting higher permissions than you need. Instead of running `su - admin` it's usually better to figure out which commands Jenkins needs to run *as* admin and put those into your sudoers file directly.

Say you need to run the following programs as user `admin` as part of your Jenkins job:

```
/usr/bin/execute
/home/admin/calculate
/opt/synergize
```

Your sudoers file could look something like this (assuming your Jenkins user is `jenkins`):

```
jenkins ALL = (admin) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/execute, /home/admin/calculate, /opt/synergize
```

This would allow the `jenkins` user to run the following commands without a password:

```
sudo -u admin /usr/bin/execute
sudo -u admin /home/admin/calculate
sudo -u admin /opt/synergize
```

From a security standpoint this is preferred to providing `su - admin` access, since then `jenkins` could do anything `admin` could without any real restrictions. The sudoers file is [very flexible](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.25/sudoers.man.html) and you should be able to restrict jenkins while still allowing it to do the job it needs to do.