# create python virtual enviroment in jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtual enviroment inside a Jenkins pipeline

```
stage('build') {
        steps {

            sh script:'''
                            #/bin/bash
                              pip install virtualenv --user

                              # Get an unique venv folder to using *inside* workspace
                              VENV=".local"

                              # Initialize new venv
                              virtualenv "$VENV"

                              # Update pip
                              PS1="${PS1:-}" source "$VENV/bin/activate"


                                pip install --user -r requirements.txt
                                '''

        }
    }
```

I also tried a

```
withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
```

command at the beginning of the stage and I keep getting this error

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'
>   Check the permission

I wonder what I am doing wrong and how to solve it..I do not want to use plug in I just would like to use a shell script to make the build stage

I am running Jenkins on MacOS

Comment: because your jenkins user is not allowed to do so.

Comment: how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudo inside Jenkins pipeline script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379157/sudo-inside-jenkins-pipeline-script)

Answer (score 0):

try instead

```
VENV="`pwd`/.local"
```

or perhaps

```
VENV="$HOME/.local"
```

since you know home

Comment: it fails when I run                                   source "$VENV/bin/activate"

Answer (score 0):

this is what solved (without creating a virtual env)

```
    stage('build') {
        steps {
            withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
            sh script:'''
                            #/bin/bash
                            echo "PATH is: $PATH"
                              python --version
                              python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
                              ls
                              pip install --user -r requirements.txt
                              export PATH="$WORKSPACE/.local/bin:$PATH"
                                '''
            }
        }
    }
```